# Link to reference for d3 network graph overlay

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Would like to ask a simple question. I would like to create an overlay layer on top of the link element in d3 network graph. Is there a sample I can follow? I have been trying to search but I can't find any example for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by an overlay layer?

Comment: Something like if I have an arrow showing a relationship between two nodes, I'd like to have an opaque box drawn on top of the arrow to make it easier to detect mouseover action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good example that I can think of is used by [Node-RED](https://nodered.org/) to draw their flow diagrams...

Create multiple network links between each pair of nodes -- the first would be a transparent "background" link with a "wide" stroke (e.g. 20px). Then draw the visible link directly on top of it, but use css to set `pointer-events: none;`. This enables the mouse enter/exit/hover events to be detected over the wider background lines, whenever the pointer is "near" the visible link.

[image]

Their technique also uses a third "outline" link in white that is 1 px wider than the visible link (between the background and foreground links). This helps to provide a half pixel of separation between the visible links in areas where there are lots of overlapping lines...